# OpenVPN Api generating ovpn file

Tags: java, api, openvpn

I need to generate a ovpn file using the OpenVPN API in a Java application, however I can't seem to find any information on this API. Does anyone have any experience or information that can get me started?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, I found this information for anyone else struggeling with this:

```
OpenVPN-AS REST API
-------------------

The OpenVPN Access Server supports a Web Services API that can be
used to fetch a client configuration file from the Access Server.

The curl command can be used to easily access this API as follows:

  curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD https://ACCESS_SERVER:CWS_PORT/rest/METHOD

Any generic HTTPS client tool (including even a web browser) can be used
to access the API -- curl is just used here as an example.  Whatever
method is used, the USERNAME:PASSWORD pair should be passed to the API
using HTTP Basic Authentication.

Replace the above variables in the curl command as follows:

USERNAME -- the username of the Access Server user for whom a configuration
            file is sought.

PASSWORD -- the password of the Access Server user for whom a configuration
            file is sought.

ACCESS_SERVER -- the domain name or public IP address of the Access Server.

CWS_PORT -- the port that the client web server is listening on.  Usually
            443 but may be different based on the specific Access Server
            configuration.  This is normally the same port that you would
            use to connect to the Client Web Server UI.

METHOD:

  * GetUserlogin -- get an OpenVPN client configuration file
    that will require a username and password to connect to the Access
    Server.

  * GetAutologin -- get an OpenVPN configuration file that will
    authenticate with the Access Server using only a client
    certificate, with no username and password required.  This is ideal
    for unattended clients such as routers, servers, or appliances.
    Note that for Autologin configurations, the user (specified by
    USERNAME) must have the Autologin permission enabled in the User
    Permissions page of the Access Server Admin UI.

  * GetGeneric -- get a generic OpenVPN configuration file that is not
    customized to a particular user.  This type of configuration is
    used in External PKI mode, when client certificates/keys are
    distributed out-of-band relative to the OpenVPN configuration
    file.  Also note that when External PKI mode is enabled, both
    GetUserlogin and GetAutologin methods return the generic
    version configuration file.

On success, the web services API will return the OpenVPN client configuration
file as content-type text/plain.

On error, an error message will be returned as content-type text/xml.  These
are some of the common error returns:

Authentication failed (bad USERNAME or PASSWORD):

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Type>Authorization Required</Type>
  <Synopsis>REST method failed</Synopsis>
  <Message>AUTH_FAILED: Server Agent XML method requires authentication (9007)</Message>
</Error>

User does not have permission to use an Autologin profile:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
  <Type>Internal Server Error</Type>
  <Synopsis>REST method failed</Synopsis>
  <Message>NEED_AUTOLOGIN: User 'USERNAME' lacks autologin privilege (9000)</Message>
</Error>

Handling challenge/response authentication:

It is possible that the server may issue a challenge to the authentication
request, for example suppose we have a user called 'test' and a password
of 'mypass".  Get the OpenVPN config file:

  curl -u test:mypass https://ACCESS_SERVER/rest/GetUserlogin

But instead of immediately receiving the config file,
we might get a challenge instead:

<Error>
  <Type>Authorization Required</Type>
  <Synopsis>REST method failed</Synopsis>
  <Message>CRV1:R,E:miwN39AlF4k40Fd8X8r9j74FuOoaJKJM:dGVzdA==:Turing test: what is 1 x 3? (9007)</Message>
</Error>

a challenge is indicated by the "CRV1:" prefix in the <Message> (meaning
Challenge Response protocol Version 1).  The CRV1 message is formatted
as follows:

CRV1:<flags>:<state_id>:<username_base64>:<challenge_text>

flags : a series of optional, comma-separated flags:
  E : echo the response when the user types it
  R : a response is required

state_id: an opaque string that should be returned to the server
along with the response.

username_base64 : the username formatted as base64

challenge_text : the challenge text to be shown to the user

After showing the challenge_text and getting a response from the user
(if R flag is specified), the client should resubmit the REST
request with the USERNAME:PASSWORD field in the HTTP header set
as follows:

<username decoded from username_base64>:CRV1::<state_id>::<response_text>

Where state_id is taken from the challenge request and response_text
is what the user entered in response to the challenge_text.
If the R flag is not present, response_text may be the empty
string.

Using curl to respond to the turing test given in the example above:

  curl -u "test:CRV1::miwN39AlF4k40Fd8X8r9j74FuOoaJKJM::3" https://ACCESS_SERVER/rest/GetUserlogin

If the challenge response (In this case '3' in response to the turing
test) is verified by the server, it will then return the configuration
file per the GetUserlogin method.
```

Comment: Question, does this only fetch a cert for existing users? Because how does a user you create have permission to for example use an Autologin profile if they haven't been created yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following GitHub project [openvpn-api](https://github.com/cloudposse/openvpn-api). It is:

> Simple OpenVPN API with capabilities limited to generating client certificates by wrapping easyrsa

written on [golang](https://golang.org/). It is just a wrapper for openvpn commands, so it is easy to rewrite it on any other technology. Some basic commands could be found in the article [How To Set Up an OpenVPN Server on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04).