# Where is the Openvpn Access Server API

Tags: api, openvpn

I knew from around that there is an API for the openvpn AS (access Server), I kept looking around their website and found nothing .

Check out the answer here :
[OpenVPN Api generating ovpn file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187499/openvpn-api-generating-ovpn-file)

Where is the documentation for the API ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it in the files of the openvpn-as itself or directly from here :
https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/access-server/openvpn-access-server-command-line-tools.html

These are the command line tools helpful todo some magic work from the command line controlling users and the openvpn AS database .

Comment: but this is not the api doc... not the XML-RPC/REST-API doc.